# Is there a performance difference between using mmap with PROT_NONE versus PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I want to mmap a larger region of memory which I only expect to use a small portion of. The memory that is used needs read and write permissions.

Is there are difference between the following two methods for mmaping the virtual memory:

```
mmap(0, size, PROT_NONE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NORESERVE, (-1), 0)
```

and then using

```
mprotect(address, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE)
```

when I need a page

versus just mmaping the entire region with PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE permissions from the start i.e

```
mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NORESERVE, (-1), 0)
```

edit for better context into my platform:

CPU model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz

Kernel Version  : 5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP

Comment: This may be very platform dependent.

Comment: By platform dependent do you mean hardware or exact linux version?

Comment: Both. Kernel internals may differ even with the same API and ABI. And OpenBSD may differ from FreeBSD and macOS. And it may differ between CPU architectures.

Comment: Kernel version is not the same as Ubuntu version. For kernel version, issue the command uname -a from a terminal

Comment: If you're trying to use `PROT_NONE` to prevent inadvertent writing, that's one thing [debatable use because it means your program goes awry]. If, you're using `mprotect` to say: "I no longer need this region of the memory/file" or "I will soon need the data from this region", I think you want `madvise` instead

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any performance benefit of keeping unneeded memory as `PROT_NONE`, and syscalls take time, so it's almost certainly faster to allocate all of the memory with `PROT_READ` and `PROT_WRITE` the first time, rather than making extra syscalls to do that later. If you want to confirm this on your own system, then just write a benchmark that tries both ways.